# Read java table in blue prism

Tags: java, blueprism, rpa

I am trying to read a java table in to a collection using blue prism read stage. But it keeps failing with below exception.

*Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.*

It seems like an issue in blue prism implementation of reading java tables using visual basic. But is there anyway to rectify this issue?

Comment: What java table? What are the contents of said table and what types? Seems like you want to read e.g. a big `long` value into a smaller type like `int` which then results in an overflow

Comment: It's a JTable (javax.swing.Jtable). I checked data, there are not many records. Also I could not find any big values in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest few options that might help:

1. Use "ignorenotshowing" option in Application Wizard, it will ignore elements that are reported to be not showing. It might be the case that some invisible part of a table is causing the error.
2. Try to identify one cell from the table, make it dynamic and iterate through the entire table reading values one by one. If you are not able to spy single cell, look for it in the Application Navigator.
3. Try using different spy modes: AA or Ui.
4. As a last resort you can just click the table, select all & copy. Then read it from the clipboard.

Comment: Tried options 1 to 3. There was no help. However last option worked. Thanks!